# Prolog find number of occurrences in a matrix

Tags: prolog

I'm able to find the number of occurrences in 1D list, but right now i'm trying to find the number of occurrences in a matrix, for example `A[3][3]`.

Here's my current code:-

```
?-countall([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],X,Y).

count([],X,0).
count([X|T],X,Y):-
    count(T,X,Z), 
    Y is 1+Z.

count([X1|T],X,Z):- 
    X1\=X,
    count(T,X,Z).

countall(List,X,C) :-
    sort(List,List1),
    member(X,List1),
    count(List,X,C).
```

my input for the matrix would be something like this:-

```
?-countall([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]).
```

Comment: IMHO I would not call this a matrix but a `list of list`. IIRC by searching for `list of list` you should find your answer in a previous SO Q&A.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem.

Comment: @GuyCoder I have another question if you don't mind, I'm trying to get the sum of every rows and columns in a matrix(list of list), i know how to do the rows but I don't have any clues for the columns, mind giving me some hints?

Comment: You should really post that as a new question and show the input, output and what you have tried. I suspect that your code for rows can be slightly modified for rows and cols both and then adding two different predicates; one for rows and one for cols.